# "Match the Shoes" challenge where is my mistake

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to solve this challenge:

The popularity order of an item is defined as follows:

- Item A is more popular than item B if it was ordered more times than
  item B.
- If item A and item B were ordered an equal number of times, then the
  item with a smaller ID (see below) is more popular.

Choosing the right pair of shoes to purchase with an article of clothing is not an obvious decision. Given the purchase frequency for shoes that were previously purchased with an item, can you help a customer by showing them the K most popular shoes (in popularity order)?

**Input Format**

The first line i contains three space-separated integers describing the following respective values:

1. K - The number of most popular shoes you must suggest.
2. M- The number of distinct shoe IDs.
3. N- The number of orders.

Each line i of the N subsequent lines (where 0<=i

**Constraints**

- 1<=K<=100
- K<=M<=50000
- 1<=N<=1000000
- 0<=Ai<=M

**Output Format**

Sort your list of K shoe suggestions in order of highest to lowest popularity, and then print each element of the prioritized list on a new line.

**Sample Input**

```
3 4 8
2
1
2
0
3
3
1
2
```

**Sample Output**

```
2
1
3
```

**Explanation**

- The shoes with ID=2 appeared 3 times. Because this is the most
  popular item, we print it first.
- The shoes with ID=1 and ID=3 appear 2 times each. Because both shoes
  appear the same number of times, they are prioritized by ascending ID
  number and printed on the second and third lines.
- Shoe ID=0 is not part of this list, as its popularity rank is less
  than K=3.

[link](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/zalando-codesprint/challenges/match-the-shoes) but my solution does not pass all the cases, can someone point me where am I doing a mistake. I am passing cases 6,9,15,16,18,19,20 and 21. but the rest are failing. Maybe my solution is also not optimal if you have any constructive criticism I am welcome to hear it. 
Thank you!

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class Solution {
    static int numberOfInputElements = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int inputArray[] = new int[numberOfInputElements];
        for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
            inputArray[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        int K = inputArray[0];
        int M = inputArray[1];
        int N = inputArray[2];

        // Constrains check
        if ((K >= 1 && K <= 100) && (K <= M && M <= 50_000) && (1 <= N && N <= 1_000_000)) {
            int orders[] = new int[N];
            for (int i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
                orders[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            }
            scanner.close();
            Map<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap();
            for (int x : orders) {
                if (!hm.containsKey(x)) {
                    if ((hm.keySet().size() >= 0) && (hm.keySet().size() <= M)) {
                        hm.put(x, 1);
                    } else
                        return;
                } else {
                    hm.put(x, hm.get(x) + 1);
                }
            }
            ArrayList result =  new ArrayList();
            result = sortByValue(hm);
            for (int i=0; i<K;i++){
                System.out.println(result.get(i));
            }
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The arguments does not look right!");
        }
    }

    private static ArrayList sortByValue(Map<Integer, Integer> unsortMap) {

        // 1. Convert Map to List of Map
        List<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> list =
                new LinkedList<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>(unsortMap.entrySet());

        // 2. Sort list with Collections.sort(), provide a custom Comparator
        //    Try switch the o1 o2 position for a different order
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>() {
            public int compare(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> o2, Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> o1) {
                return (o1.getValue()).compareTo(o2.getValue());
            }
        });

        // 3. Loop the sorted list and put it into a new insertion order Map LinkedHashMap
        ArrayList  arrayList =  new ArrayList();
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : list) {
            arrayList.add(entry.getKey());    
        }
        return arrayList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't just link an external page. Give a precise description of the involved failig cases and why they fail.

Comment: Please block-quote the gist of the problem statement in your question - a hyperlink is welcome for details and reference.

Comment: don't use linked list for sorting. use array list

Comment: (since it is solved) I think you can also use priority queue.

Comment: You can further improve the complexity to N log (k). Since, `k` is as small as `100`, it somehow corresponds to ~O(N). We just maintain a priority queue of size `k`. https://ideone.com/JEDihV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't find any logical problem,so submitted your code.It works fine.

[image: Works Fine]

Comment: for me is failing :(

Comment: now passed after second time.